# How to add more options in Magento like bestsellars, featured products, most viewed products

Tags: php, magento

I am using Sahara Magento theme, usually I deal with words like Best Sellers, Most Viewed, Featured, New Product, Random Products in Magento, what are they actually?

Are they Categories, or tags, or something else? Issue I am facing is I am having options like this on my home page : this is coming from products tabs.

[image]

I need these best sellers to change with

NEW ARRIVAL, BESTSELLERS, SALE, PROMOTION, PRE-LOVED, PRE-ORDER, BACK-ORDER

I tried checking all back-end, But all I got is this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Labels in the Front-end...

Find your IP so you're the only one who can edit.

Go to `System > Configruation > Advanced (All the way down) > Developper` then add your IP in the first tab "Developper Client Restriction", open the 4th tab "Translate Inline" and select YES for "Enabled for front end"

Now go to the front-end and you should be able to edit the labels when you hover them.

[image: System > Configruation > Advanced > Developper]

Comment: First of all thanks for replying, secondly, your solutions seems about only editing labels, not the things, like if i only change labels, suppose, if i changed most viewed label to pre order, how i will choose which products are pre loved and all that ?

Comment: Sorry I read ur question a little too fast. These are options from your theme, why don't go ask the developer of the theme. If you got it on theme forest, search the comments for an answer.